# Styling contenteditable with jQuery within a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i'm creating a **basic app to learn Backbone.js**. In my code, I have the following template.

```
<script type="text/template" id="userTemplate">
  <span class="nome"><%= nome %></span>
  <span class="sobrenome"><%= sobrenome %></span>
  <a href="#" class="editar">Editar</a>
  <a href="#" class="remover">Remover</a>
</script>
```

`.editar` click event handler:

```
editar: function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var style = {
        color: 'green',
        height: '70px',
        border: '2px solid green'
    };

    $('.sobrenome').attr('contenteditable', true).focus();
    $('.sobrenome').css(style);
},
```

I have been trying to style a `contenteditable` using jQuery's `css()` but for some reason, the css won't apply on the content.

```
this.$('.sobrenome').attr('contenteditable', true).css(style).focus();
```

What is wrong? In my views, everything is ok.

Comment: remove the `this` before your `$('.sobrenome')`

Comment: still does not work.

Comment: I've never seen HTML inside the script tag, so not sure if that's legit or something to do with your template/backbone...

Comment: @Milanzorg this is valid in Backbone.

Comment: @AmericanSlime you can put anything between script tag if the `type` is something else than `text/javascript` and it won't show up on the page. Then you can recover the content with JavaScript.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron ah didnt know that! Also didnt see the backbone tag. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Backbone, I thought I'd provide a simple Backbone view which toggle the `contenteditable` attribute and is stylized by default with CSS.

Avoid applying CSS with JavaScript and whenever possible, prefer toggling classes instead in order to keep the style and the logic completely separated.

To stylize something only when `contenteditable` is true, you can use the following selector.

```
[contenteditable="true"] { 
    /* css */
}
```

I simplified the code for the example's sake. I added a simple `blur` handler to remove `contenteditable` when the user clicks outside the element.

```js
var ContentEditableView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#userTemplate').html()),
  events: {
    "click .edit": 'onEdit',
    "blur .content": 'onEditDone'
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      content: "test",
      nome: "test nome",
    }));

    // caching jQuery object is better than querying the DOM each time.
    this.$content = this.$('.content');
    return this;
  },

  onEdit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.$content.attr('contenteditable', true).focus();
  },
  onEditDone: function() {
    this.$content.attr('contenteditable', false);
  }
});

var view = new ContentEditableView({
  el: $('#app')
});
view.render();
```

```css
/* keep CSS out of the JS */
[contenteditable="true"] {
  color: green;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="userTemplate">
  <span class="content"><%= content %></span>
  <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
</script>
```

Comment: that was a awesome answer. i was trying do sothing dinamic. but you show a sample way to do. thanks @Emile

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be this part:

```
this.$('.sobrenome')
```

I don't believe you can combine a native `this` with a jQuery selector, you need to turn the `this` into something jQuery can work with, so try the following...

```
$(this).$('.sobrenome')
```

However, even making that change doesn't make sense because you don't concatenate with `.` in JavaScript. Chaining selectors like that won't do much of anything.

Comment: i try remove this. and also i try do with $(this).$('.sobrenome'). both without success.

Comment: @adahox_ You'll have to show more code, such as the HTML, because it's unclear what you're trying to target. I don't know if you're trying to combine selectors or what.

Comment: `.$(selector)` is a Backbone view function which is an alias to `this.$el.find(selector)`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your goal? I put the styles in a class and removed the unnecessary(?) `this`

```js
$('.sobrenome').attr('contenteditable', true).focus();
```

```css
.sobrenome{
     color: green;
     height:70px;
     border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sobrenome">asasf</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var style = {
     color: 'green',
     height:'70px',
     border: '2px solid green'
};

$('.sobrenome').each(function() {
  var _state = $(this).attr('data-contenteditable');
  if (_state === 'true') {
    $(this).css(style).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sobrenome" data-contenteditable="false">Unstyled element</div>
<div class="sobrenome" data-contenteditable="true">Sstyled element</div>
```